# Trouble creating a dynamic jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a dynamic selector and dump view the resulting object in the console log:

```
console.log($('input:first[type=hidden][id$='+ temp +']').parent());
```

translation: get the parent of the first input which is hidden and where the id ends with 'temp'

temp is a var that is passed into the function where this statement lives.  When I take out the + temp + and replace it with say... 50 (a known number) - I get the result I am looking for.  When I try to get the selector to print dynamically, I get an empty result.  I have searched and searched for a solution but cannot find a solution.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

```
function removeAjaxContact(aid)
{
    console.log(aid);
    console.log($('input:first[type=hidden][id$='+ aid +']').parent());
}
```

console result:

```
`40

[]`
```

SELF ANSWERED:

OK - figured it out... I passed the value into from the page as a string instead of an int.  not sure why that made the difference, but it did.  thank you all for your quick reply and support!!

Comment: @Ibu that's the "id ends with" part.

Comment: Paste your whole block, or add `console.log(temp)` to see what temp is

Comment: I do the console.log(temp) and get the expected result... I am so baffled at why this won't work!  I have also tried using temp.toString()...

Comment: `.toString()` is unnecessary when concatenating. Could you show us some markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Stated above in an edit): OK - figured it out... I passed the value into from the page as a string instead of an int (encapsulated in quotes). not sure why that made the difference, but it did. thank you all for your quick reply and support!!

Update, I have run into this problem in passing other values too, passing an int will randomly lead to getting a lower number in the actual function.  I am a little green do diagnose why this is happening.  Thanks to you all for the instant help and support!